# How do I properly have a different css file for each html tempate in a Flask project?

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2

I have started a Flask project and to stay organized I would like to have a css file per html file. A lot of the tutorials online have one css file in the /static/styles.css file. When I run the following code, the css does not seem to be used and the terminal of the flask connection gives:
 `127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2019 20:49:30] "GET /%7B%7B%20url_for('static',%20filename='css/index.css')%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -` but it does load the page, just no css. Is there a standard way to have multiple css files in the static directory.

My project structure is:

```
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
venv
app
 -> main.py
 -> templates
    -> index.html
 -> static
    -> css
       -> index.css
```

My main.py file is :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)


# Set-up Flask routes.
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

My index.html file is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% block head %}
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css"  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}"/>
</head>
{% endblock %}

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <strong><nav>
       <ui class="menu">
         <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav></strong>
  </header>
```

My index.css file is:

```
.menu li {
    display: 'inline-block";
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring whether that's a good idea or not, your css file is called `index.css` and sits in the root of the `static` folder, yet you're trying to include a file called `layout.css` that sits in a folder called `css` within the static folder. Try this for example `<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css"  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}"/>`

Comment: MY bad, I should have clarified. I have the css files in a css sub folder. Let me update my question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little later, I found the solution for this:
In my/your `base.html` define a jinja template for the stylesheet so all pages have that as a default but can be overridden.

```
    {% block stylesheet %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base.css') }}"/>
    {% endblock stylesheet %}
```

Then in another html file say `posts.html`, the stylesheet tag can be used to change it,

```
    {% block stylesheet %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/posts.css') }}"/>
    {% endblock stylesheet %}
```

This allows use of multiple css files. However, this means all css will be overridden and used from the new css so there will be a lot of duplication across files. However, to me this makes it more organized and readable. It is a matter of preference. Good luck